# Outline ImageLine Art from Edge Mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, line-art, adobe-lightroom

I've been trying to figure out how to create black and white line art from my photographs. I've got illustrator, photoshop and Lightroom. Image trace in illustrator kind of works (I'm probably/definitely doing something wrong) but it's not giving the result I'm after.

For example of what I mean is when you go into Lightroom and in the sharpening tab, hold alt on the masking option. What that creates is what I want a copy of, black outlines with the rest white/blank. The images are RAW 16MP images taken with a DSLR.

Comment: So you need something sketch-like, ya? Maybe you could find something in the "Filter Gallery" in Photoshop.

Comment: I didn't know that existed. Photocopy seems to do the job pretty well thanks :) Are there any other ways those effects can be done. If the filters don't do a good job for example.

Comment: There is another option: `image => adjustments => threshold` and then "blurify" it but it's far more bad-looking and you need special plugin, in example Topaz DeNoise, to decrease the level of spiky edges.

Comment: @SylwesterPilarz Put your comments as an answer. Images are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Photoshop, there is something like gallery of available photofilters: `Filter => Filter Gallery`

Then, you have a `Sketch` folder, when you can find a lot of nice filters to do the sketch-like picture. For your purpose, I recommend a `Photocopy` option. It looks like this:
[image]

After choosing best options, it should looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yep that's pretty much what I need. Thank you so much. Played with the threshold as well. These are the results I've got from screwing around with a jpeg, I'll do it properly later. 
https://imgur.com/a/28N4T

Comment: If this answers your question don't forget to choose it as best answer!

Comment: Will do, I assume it's the little green arrow on the left? First time on site.